# Why is this happening?

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting

[image]

This weird connection lines appears when I use texture paint.
How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Hello and welcome! can you share a blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Your UVs are outside the UV region look at the sides of them, the texture for the UVs that are outside the UV region gets repeated so you gotta re-unwrap and scale it to smaller than the bounds of UV region